# how add class between date and time?

Tags: php, class, date, time

I use date syntax code for output current date and time.
date formated : l,D F Y  h:i
I want add class on  time(h:i)
ex:

```
l,D F Y  <dic class="timeclass">h:i</div>
```

how do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<?php echo echo date("l,D F Y"); ?> <div class="class-name"><?php echo date("h:i") ?></div>
```

This should work.